# Detect if AIR application is running on a phone or other device that can make phone calls?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have an AIR application that runs on iDevice and Android, for tablets and phones.

I am trying to add functionality to turn displayed phone numbers into links that allow the user to launch a call to that number, but I only want this to happen on devices that can actually make phone calls (i.e. primarily on phones, not tablets).

Is there an easy way of detecting whether the application is running on a phone?

Comment: Assuming that the functionality is exposed via an underlying API, you may have to create a NativeExtension.

Comment: As I understand it, both Android and iDevice have native methods for this, but it is a fairly minor bit of functionality that I didn't particularly want to write an ANE for! I was really hoping that there was something like `Capabilities.hasPhone;`

Comment: As far as I know; AIR does not expose this in any way.  Since AIR can't handle phone calls, I'm sure this was not built into the AIR API.